# Redireccinar Dominio a servidor local apache, manteniendo url original en carpetas y subcarpetas

Tags: html, apache

Tengo un servidor gratuito, que quiero utilzar para redireccionar a mi servidor
local apache, manteniendo su url original, en todo mi servidor local apache, tanto en carpetas, como en sub-carpetas. Al utilizar el siguiente codigo se logra mantener la url origen pero solo en la carpeta raiz, PERO no en las carpetas y sub-carpetas. Ya que al pasar el cursor por encima de ellas, se muestra la direccion ip Publica real de mi servidor local apache.

Como hago para que la url origen se muestre en todo mi sitio local apache, incluyendo carpetas y sub-carpetas ?

Gracias.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>/</title>
</head>
<frameset rows=’100%, *’ frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://miservidorlocalapache:#puerto/"
name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes>
Su navegador no soporta frames. Le recomendamos actualizar su navegador.
</noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucion:**

Con un dominio gratuito o de pago, apuntar los servidores de nombres
a cloudflare.com y desde alli configurar los registros de tipo A que apunten
a la direccion IP publica del servidor local apache. Si se utiliza el puerto 80
no hay problemas, pero si se desea utilizar un puerto diferente, en la seccion de ayuda, buscar los puertos que se utilizan para el correcto funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el frame lo único que hace es cargar una página dentro de otra pero siempre desde donde esté alojada, es decir, no "enmascara" la ubicación real donde está hospedado. Creo que lo más práctico para lo que quieres, si tienes un dominio propio, es redirigir el DNS a tu servidor local y te evitas problemas.

Espero que te haya servido

Comment: Gracias por esponder. El dominio propio funciona, pero lo tengo ocupado con otro proyecto. ¿ No habra alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Por ejemplo con .htacces, u otro metodo ?

Comment: Y un subdominio? (en plan http://app2.midominio.com/)

Comment: Esto del subdominio no me queda claro. ¿Es comprar un domnio en esa pagina SIN Hosting, y que se puedan crear subdominios ?

Comment: Pense que con mi dominio propio funcionaria, y tampoco funciona, solo enmascara la url en la barra de direcciones, y nada mas. Al pasar el cursor por las carpetas, o archivos, se ve mi IP Publica real. Asi que tal vez sea modificando el archivo httpd.conf, o alguna otra cosa ? o poder ocultar mi IP Publica de otra forma ?

Comment: no te sabría decir, pero prueba con esto a ver si te ayuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: esto solo sirve para crear subdominios, pero no sirve para ocultar la ip. Pero creo que tal vez lo que deseo se pueda hacer con el .htacces,pero ni idea como sera.